Induced charges due to uniform electric field
Suppose there is a finite metallic conductor placed in a uniform electric field. Will the magnitude of positive or negative charge induced on it depend on its shape or will it only depend on the magnitude of the electric field?

No need to shout in the title

$\dots$ will it depend on the magnitude of the electric field?
No electric field inside a conductor, when there is an external field, means that charges must move within the conductor (induced charges) to produce an electric field due to the induced charges in opposition to the external electric field.
A larger external electric field means that the induced charges must also produce a larger electric field in opposition, hence there must be more induced charges.
Will the magnitude of positive charge induced on it depend on its shape $\dots$
The introduction of a conductor into a region which previously had an electric field must result in the conductor becoming an equipotential and this is the result of there being induced charges on the surface of the conductor.
Equipotential means that the work done in bringing charge from a point outside the conductor to the surface of the conductor must be path-independent.
The induced charge distributes itself so the the equal work done condition is satisfied.
A convex surface which is part of a conductor will have a greater induced surface charge density than a concave surface.
If the surface charge density was the same then it would require less work to be done if the surface is convex because more surface charges would be further away from the incoming charge than if the surface was concave.
A conductor at right angles to the external electric field would have a large surface charge density at the edges to make sure that the work done bringing in a charge along an electric field to the centre of the plate is the same as the incoming charge reaching the edge of the conductor.
In general, a quantitative answer can only be achieved by numerical calculations but Conducting sphere in a uniform electric field is an example of an analytic solution.

(1) When you put an isolated finite metallic object into an uniform electric field, there will be an equal amount of positive and negative charge induced. The total induced charge is thus zero.
(2) If you consider only the positive induced charge, then its magnitude will strongly depend on the size, shape and orientation of the object.

General Proof of your statement 2??
